# not able to read selection box value from angular js

Tags: angularjs

in my jade

```
  select.thumbnail.form-control(ng-
  model="txtPaymentStatus",id="txtPaymentStatus", 
  ng-options="type.type for type in PaymentStatus")
```

in my angular js file

```
   $scope.PaymentStatus = [{ type : "Pending" }, { type : "Done" }];
   console.log($scope.txtPaymentStatus);
```

here the output is undefined. why? please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You see undefined there because that console.log is run when the controller is made and nothing is selected and you have not set a value to $scope.txtPaymentStatus.

```js
var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.select']);

app.controller('myController', function($scope) {
   $scope.PaymentStatus = [{ type : "Pending" }, { type : "Done" }];
   console.log($scope.txtPaymentStatus);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.3/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-select/0.12.1/select.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app='app' ng-controller='myController'>
  <select class="thumbnail form-control" ng-model="txtPaymentStatus" id="txtPaymentStatus" ng-options="type.type for type in PaymentStatus"></select>
  {{ txtPaymentStatus }}
</div>
```